# How to prevent Vuejs scrolling to the top of the page when you press the browser back button

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

It looks like Vuejs is automatically scrolling to the top of a page when you push the back button, which is weird because by default the window doesnt even scroll to the top when you change route in a SPA or go to a new page. You need to explicitly set scrollBehaviour to scroll to the top. So how can we prevent the page automatically scrolling to the top when you press the back button.

```
beforeRouteLeave (to, from, next) {
    alert('Are you sure you want to leave this page and lose unsaved changes')
    // Notice how the page automatically scrolls to the top here even if the user were to response 'No' in a dialog situation
}
```

Heres a code pen of the problem
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bOGqVP

Comment: You can return a promise that resolves to some coordinates object instead of an object itself. Does that help you?

Comment: Could you give me a link to this solution kind sir!? I have found somewhat similar approaches but they arent working. Upon further inspection it appears scrollBehaviour hasnt yet kicked in when the page auto scrolls to the top. Its something else in the browser or vue engine causing this behaviour

Comment: If the problem exists even when `scrollBehavior` is commented out, you probably should look for other culprits. Are you clicking a link with `href="#"`?

Comment: So strange. I just made a codepen to show this problem. its actually got nothing to do with scroll behaviour. it seems internal to vuejs or the browser https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bOGqVP

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Browser back button scroll to top is defined by browser. Aparently we can disable that behaviour by adding this line of code

```
window.history.scrollRestoration = "manual"
```

Adding this code will tell browser that we handle the scroll.
I only test this in your codepen. Need testing in other browser

Comment: Accepting this as its the only thing so far i have found that works. Great work man. not too sure about browser support yet but working on chrome which is ok for me :) Thanks